# How to find rally workspace and project name for pyral connection

Tags: python, pyral

How to find workspace and project name in rally for pyral arguments

Pyral documentation was not clear

```
import sys
from pyral import Rally, rallyWorkset
server = "rally1.rallydev.com"
user = "xxx"
password = "zzz"
workspace = ""
project = ""
rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find it out to login to Rally and check it in UI:
[image]

Just enter arguments as it is:

```
rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace="My WorkSpace", project="Root Project")
```